# For a string that consists of a number algorithm

Tags: java, string, algorithm, int

If I want to make an algorithm that has the following rules:

> Working from right to left,
>
> sum the digits in the odd-numbered positions (first, third, fifth,
>   etc.) and multiply the total by three;
>
> sum the digits in the even-numbered positions (second, fourth, sixth,
>   etc.);

Question 1: How do I make int or double accept the number "0" in the beginning to prevent it from seeing that I am trying to use octal.

Question 2: Specifically how to get the specific positions, I have thought of putting it into a string and trying to think of using sub string but I don't see how it would work. Though I have thought of something like

```
  String a = "036000291452";
for (int b = 0; a.length() > b; b + 2) {
    String c = a.substring(b)
//some converting * 3...
}
```

to try to get the odd position (or even) and then converting it into int. But that doesn't print out one position. Thanks in advance for any help and any consideration.

Comment: It sounds like you'd have to parse an input string one character at a time to solve this. I suggest using `String.charAt(int)` and converting the results to a number of some kind.

Comment: You may also find it useful to use a for-each loop to go through the String instead of using `String.charAt(int)`, and instead use `String a = "123"; for(char c : a) //do stuff with c`

Comment: When you say odd and even position you are saying odd and even from the end? So if the string is 1234 even odd are 4 and 2 and even are 3 and 1 or viceversa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make `int` or `double` accept the number "0" in the beginning to prevent it from seeing that I am trying to use octal?

Since you are passing the number as a string, octal/decimal convention for integer literals does not apply in your situation. Generally, through, you remove leading zeros from your numeric constant.

> Specifically how to get the specific positions

Since you are working from right to left, start at `a.length()-1`, and go down by two, until you get to a negative index.

To get a digit from string `a` at position `i` use [`Character.digit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit(char,%20int)), like this:

```
int digit = Character.digit(a.charAt(i), 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to do what you said.
Simply sum even and odd digits

```
public int mycalc(String s) {
    int odd = 0;
    int even = 0;
    for (int b = 0; b < s.length(); b++) {
        // This is the int value of the b-th character of the string
        int digit = s.charAt(b) - '0';   

        if (b % 2 == 0) {
            even += digit;
        } else {
            odd += digit;
        }
    }
   odd *= 3;
   return odd + even;   // Or do what you need with odd and even 
}
```

Comment: If I understood the OP correctly, ordering happens right-to-lift.

Comment: Making a sum from left to right or from right to left is the same: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 is equals to 4 + 3 + 2 + 1

Comment: Not if the string has an odd length, in that case even and odd indices differ when counting starts from the beginning or the end.

Comment: Mmmmm.... yes, I think it is not really clear from the question. I try to add a comment to the owner of the question to be sure. If even and odd are calculated from the end I will change the loop direction.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're supposed to work from right to left, I'd say that the right-most position is position 1. If working with a String you could do this:

```
String input = "036000291452";
int sumOdd = 0, sumEven = 0;
for (int pos = 1; pos <= input.length(); pos++) {
    if (pos % 2 == 1) {
        sumOdd += input.charAt(input.length() - pos) - '0';
    } else {
        sumEven += input.charAt(input.length() - pos) - '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind that for a string, one has to use `.length()`, not `.length`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem OOPS, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fetch the character/digit at the given position with `.charAt(int)`. So:

```
String a = "036000291452";
int odd = 0;
int eve = 0;
for(int i = a.length()-2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
    odd += a.charAt(i)-'0';
}
odd *= 3;
for(int i = a.length()-1; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
    eve += a.charAt(i)-'0';
}
//do something with odd and even
```

For instance [this jdoodle](http://jdoodle.com/a/xU) prints the result of `odd` (`42`) and `eve` (`18`).